# Google Places autocomplete Android - Not working

Tags: android, api, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am new to Android App development. 
I followed [this toturial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-places-autocomplete-api-example/) to write a simple Google Places autocomplete Android App, but it does not return any suggestions when I start typing in the app; it gives NativeCrypto error in LogCat when I write anything in the autocomplete textview. Here is my code:

```
package com.example.newxyz; 

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GooglePlacesAutocompleteActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "Google Places Autocomplete";
    private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
    private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
    private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";
    private static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyAujQlZ1Jj64NAHMoynXjI253MVRzGW09w";
    private static final String True = "true";
    private static final String language = "en";

    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView;
    @Override

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);

        autoCompView.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item));

        autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    } 



    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

        String str = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

    public static ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
        ArrayList<String> resultList = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
       try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?sensor=" + True);
            sb.append("&key=" + API_KEY);
            sb.append("&language" + language);
            //sb.append("&components=country:gr");
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));
            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());


            // Load the results into a StringBuilder

           int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);

            return resultList;
       } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {

                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
        try {           
            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");
            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                System.out.println(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
                System.out.println("============================================================");
                resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
     }
        return resultList;
    }
   class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
        private ArrayList<String> resultList;
        public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return resultList.size();
        }
        @Override
        public String getItem(int index) {
            return resultList.get(index);
        }
        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    if (constraint != null) {
                        // Retrieve the autocomplete results.

                      resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());
                        // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                        filterResults.values = resultList;
                        filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                    }
                    return filterResults;
                }
                @Override

               protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                   if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }

            };
            return filter;
       }
    }
}
```

Here is my LogCat error:

```
05-04 13:16:27.705: E/NativeCrypto(9312): ssl=0x611c0a20 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x62625940 arg=0x0
05-04 13:16:27.705: E/NativeCrypto(9312): ssl=0x611c0a20 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
```

- I have enabled Google Places API for Android in console.developers.google.com
- I am using a Browser key for my app
- I have looked for answers to my problem and haven't found any relevant answer yet
- I have given Internet permissions in the Menifest file
- In Overview of the Developer Console, the Graph is showing the requests, which means requests are made but there is no response.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: "it gives NativeCrypto error in LogCat"? Post dat logcat then please (the logger actually helps debugging)...

Comment: It might be worth taking a look at the new Places API for Android (https://developers.google.com/places/android/) which has support for Autocomplete.

Comment: @plexer I rechecked and followed each step as in the link you provided...the error persists

Comment: You mentioned that you're using a Browser key. Did you change that to an Android key?

Comment: Aisa karain try to enable Google Place API Webservice. From what I see of your code, you're using the Web API and not the Android API. And, since you're using the web API, you should use a browser key, not an Android key. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I enabled the Android API, same error and no suggestions like I want from an autocomplete textview

Answer (score 2):

Go [Google Console](https://console.developers.google.com/home/dashboard?project=eyon-1097) >> Api >> Enable Google Places API Web Service.
See [Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1far0.png)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using the Places API web service (as opposed to the Android service), you must enable the `Google Places API Web Service` API in the Google Developers Console.

Once you've got that working, if you would like to simplify your code and use a library that provides a [GooglePlaceAutoComplete](https://pushbit.github.io/sprockets-android/apidocs/index.html?net/sf/sprockets/widget/GooglePlaceAutoComplete.html) widget, check out [Sprockets](https://github.com/pushbit/sprockets-android) (I'm the developer).  After setting it up with your API key, you could add a working Places API autocomplete to your layout with something like:

```
<net.sf.sprockets.widget.GooglePlaceAutoComplete
    android:id="@+id/place"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: what use would be a library if my API key isn't working?

Comment: It looks like you just need to enable another API.  I've added the details to the answer.

Comment: I made a key for android, and enabled Google Places API for Android, but same error.

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting this issue yesterday, so it either

- Wrong `API_KEY` (e.g. you might setup different prefix to debug version in build.gradle or used wrong SH1 or register to some other rather than 'Google Places API for Android')
- If your GoogleApiClient not built with `enableAutoManage(fragmentActivity, clientId, connectionCallback)` otherwise `GoogleApiClient.blockingConnect()` or `GoogleApiClient.connect()` called

Frankly speaking, I'm not happy how #Google done this API. So odd, how to understand what's happened if you're getting code 9001, 9006, 9007 whatever?

Comment: I have trying deleting and making new API_KEY, the SH1 is working for Google Map but not Google places. And Google Places API for Android is what I registered for...I do not understand your second point. Can you please elaborate

Comment: oops, I just realized I answered wrong question. I was talking about Google Places stuff from google play services for Android. But you may be interested check this https://developers.google.com/places/android/autocomplete out.

Comment: This API wasn't really meant to be used is why, and is shutting down. Look here: http://venturebeat.com/2015/07/24/google-will-restrict-access-to-its-autocomplete-api-on-august-10-asks-developers-to-use-custom-search-engine/

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was

```
"status":"REQUEST_DENIED",
"error_message":"This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated "
```

And the solution was enable **Google Places API Web Service** in the Google Api Console.

Answer (score 0):

I fond a solution there is nothing wrong with text watcher.

In the below code I didn't override "performFiltering" method. I added it and my auto complete text box now working fine.

```
public class CustomAutoCompleteView extends AutoCompleteTextView {  

public CustomAutoCompleteView(Context context) {  
    super(context);  
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub  
}  

public CustomAutoCompleteView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {  
    super(context, attrs);  
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub  
}  

public CustomAutoCompleteView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,  
        int defStyle) {  
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);  
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub  
}  

@Override  
protected void performFiltering(final CharSequence text, final int keyCode) {  
    String filterText = "";  
    super.performFiltering(filterText, keyCode);  
}  
/** 
* After a selection, capture the new value and append to the existing 
* text 
*/  
@Override  
protected void replaceText(final CharSequence text) {  
    super.replaceText(text);  
}  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable "Google Places API Web Service" API and give it a try. It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to do something like this:

```
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));
final URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
final InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
```

It is working in my case.

Comment: Actual problem is in your API key.
When i try it with my code is not working.
But with my API key it working fine.

Comment: @HasmukhBarochiya please provide some explanation with your answer and avoid code-only answers when possible (in this case you suspect the general code or the API keys).

Comment: @shkschneider Thanks for advice. I'll do that next time.


I just want to say that the API key is not working in this case, I use same code in my app and its working fine with my API key (I use more than one key for testing purpose) but with the key provided in question its not working.

Comment: @Hasmukh Barochiya Can you please tell me what to do about the API key? I deleted my project in console.developers.google.com made a new project, made new key but its still not working...

Answer (score -1):

The solution is adding googlePlaceApi to project in console.developers.google.com